# Perl File::Monitor module notifying multiple notifications for the new file created whereas i expect one notification

Tags: perl, file, inotify

Below is the code snippet! i am using for file creatiing notification using Perl module File::Monitor.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Monitor;
use File::Basename;
use Time::HiRes qw {usleep};

my $pid,@pids;


sub textfile_notifier {
my ($watch_name, $event, $change) = @_; 

my @new_file_paths = $change->files_created; #The change object has a property called files_created, 
                                             #which contains the names of any new files
for my $path (@new_file_paths) {
    my ($base, $fname, $ext) = fileparse($path, '.log'); # $ext is "" if the '.txt' extension is
                                                         # not found, otherwise it's '.txt'.
    if ($ext eq '.log') {
        print "$path was created\n";
    #-----------------------------------------Forking part #-----------------------------------------
    defined ($pid = fork()) or die "Couldn't fork: $!";
    if ($pid == 0) { #then in child process
        print "Loop got executed\n";
    }
    else {  #then in parent process, where $pid is the pid of the child
        push @pids, $pid;
    }
    #-----------------------------------------Forking part ends here #-----------------------------------------
    }
}
}

my $monitor = File::Monitor->new();

$monitor->watch( {
name        => '/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/',
recurse     => 1,
callback    => {files_created => \&textfile_notifier},  #event => handler 1 
} );

$monitor->scan;
while (1) {
$monitor->scan; #Scanning the directory one
#sleep(2);
#usleep(10_000); #$microseconds = 750_000;
for my $pid (@pids) {
    waitpid($pid, 0)  #0 => block
}
}
```

file creation

=============================

```
touch 1.log  
touch 2.log  
touch 3.log  
touch 4.log
```

output of the script

=========================

```
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/1.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/2.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/2.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/3.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/3.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/3.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/3.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created  
/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/4.log was created
```

Where as i am expecting one notification/alert printed for one file on the terminal.
what i suspect is that there is some bug in the "Forking part" section!

any idea where's i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried removing duplicates from the array before opening the for loop? **EDIT:** Also how fast are the files being created after one another?

Comment: @Phyreprooph which duplicate entries are you talking about ? and files are generated at random intervals

Comment: @7stud can you help me here

Comment: Sorry I'm talking about possible duplicates in `@new_file_paths`. That could be the reason multiple things are being printed out. Alternatively, back up your script and remove the forking part and see what prints out. That'll tell you if it is the forking part causing this issue

Comment: @Phyreprooph Like you said after removing forking part it looks fine but yet thoroughly check multiple test cases.

Comment: What exactly are you forking for? It looks like you are exponentially creating new threads. each time you make a thread that thread then makes a thread and for every thread that is active when a file is created, they are all picking up that the file has been created and printing to the log.

**EDIT:** As far as your question goes, you are asking why you are receiving multiple outputs. You haven't provided any information about the purpose of the forking so I can't really help you with that. It doesn't look like it's doing much so if all you want is the output correct then just remove the fork.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102962/discussion-between-shantesh-and-phyreprooph).

Comment: @Phyreprooph Yes you are right! after removing the fork part it is working fine and my initial idea was to use forking to execute a script inside `if ($pid == 0) { #then in child process
        system("perl $script $path \&");
    }` and i didn't know i can do it directly ! thats the reason i was using fork looks like its works fine for me

Comment: It would be nice to have the corrected code as an approved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what solved my problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Monitor;
use File::Basename;
use Time::HiRes qw {usleep};
my $script = '/homw/goudarsh/Desktop/script.pl';
sub textfile_notifier {
my ($watch_name, $event, $change) = @_; 

my @new_file_paths = $change->files_created; #The change object has a property called files_created, 
                                         #which contains the names of any new files
for my $path (@new_file_paths) {
my ($base, $fname, $ext) = fileparse($path, '.log'); # $ext is "" if the '.txt' extension is
                                                     # not found, otherwise it's '.txt'.
if ($ext eq '.log') {
    print "$path was created\n";
    system("perl $script $path \&");
}
}}
my $monitor = File::Monitor->new();
$monitor->watch( {
name        => '/home/goudarsh/Desktop/logs/',
recurse     => 1,
callback    => {files_created => \&textfile_notifier},  #event => handler 1 
} );

$monitor->scan;
while (1) {
$monitor->scan; #Scanning the directory one
sleep(2);
#usleep(10_000); #$microseconds = 750_000;

}
```

All i wanted to execute a  `$script` with `$path` as an argument and i used forking for creating child process but i was wrong about the concept of using fork which was not needed! now without forking i can do whatever was required and i am happy for learning new things

Comment: But i am still not getting why i was getting the multiple entries when i used fork.

Comment: You weren't *exiting* in the child, so the parent and the child were both continuing through the loop, monitoring, and forking again. First time, one process. Second time, two processes. Third time, four processes. Fourth time, eight processes.

Comment: If you had more files modified (say, more than ten) you would have ended up with thousands of processes monitoring and printing.

Comment: I am actually still getting the old behaviour, ie. , first reports 1 log, then 2, 4, 8, etc. I am using code as the answer above, only I have added `my (@pids);` to take care of a compilation warning.

Comment: @gsl please delete for loop which is not required anymore

Comment: @gsl exactly this part `for my $pid (@pids) {
    waitpid($pid, 0)  #0 => block
}`

Comment: I removed that code. I now have the same code as in the answer (except of course different path to script and watched folder), but I still have the same issue. Perhaps the script does not end the while loop, and so continues to work?

Comment: @gsl the purpose of this script is to monitor a directory and trigger a notification for any *.log file generation and pass that *.log to ` $script` and i want to run this script indefinitely.